# Picking a card from an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, random, enums

My Arraylist  is an Arraylist made out of enums which have Suits and Ranks (all together 52cards)

```
    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    Random rand = new Random();
```

I created my card deck and shuffled it and now I am trying to pick a random Card.

```
    public Card dealCard() {

    int index = rand.nextInt(deck.size());
    Card cards = deck.get(index);
    return cards;
```

But my main is giving me Errors

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Deck deck1 = new Deck();
            deck1.dealCard();
            System.out.println(deck1.toString());
```

Any ideas on how I could pick that random card? I suppose it has something to do with that int and rand.nextInt as I am not picking Integers. But how can I pick my cards? Should I use my Suite.values() and Rank.values() here as well? And how do I apply them for random?
*edit: my class Card contains the enums and setters and toString and my class Deck has the methods for creating the Deck shuffling it and picking one card and then I have the static void main for running it

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The code you've posted looks OK. Post the error and a [minimal and complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the code that raises the error.

Comment: trying.Deck@6d06d69c while trying is my package

Comment: That's not an error. That's the output of  your print statement. Read this thoroughly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Comment: added the whole code now

Comment: There is no `toString()` method in `Deck` class and yet you are calling it. The result is that `Deck` class inherits a `toString()` method by default from the `Object` class and that is being called. And that method simply prints the hashcode of the object. You already have a `print` function in `Deck` class. Why do you need to call `toString()` on `Deck`. Just call `deck.print()` after `deck.dealCard()`

Comment: Your `dealCard()` is returning a random card from the deck, but is not removing it from the deck, so you may get the same card again next time you deal a card. If this is OK, it’s OK.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue I see is that you are returning the card from your `dealCard()` function, but not saving it anywhere. Try changing the last two lines to `System.out.println(deck1.dealCard().toString());`

Also I believe you are missing a `}` to close your `dealCard()` function.

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly!